# Replace A string token in Word document with a word table

Tags: .net, ms-word, range, office-interop

I am working with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application. I have some templated word document in which file there will be some Token like 
[PutfirstTableHere]
At the runtime i will create Table and want's to replace that token in the existing word document with the generated Table
Can any body let me know how can i replace a string token with Table in the Word?
Not able to find any example/sample for my current problem

Comment: Don't use tokens like that, word has bookmarks that are great for this. Use this as an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs(v=vs.80).aspx. I would also suggest using OpenXMLSdk because it doesn't require Word and it's way faster than Interop http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb456488.aspx

Comment: Can't use the OpenXmlSdk. it disturbs the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void InsertTableAtBookMark(string[][] docEnds, string bookmarkName)
    {
        Object oBookMarkName = bookmarkName;
        Range wRng = WordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMarkName).Range;

        Table wTable = WordDoc.Tables.Add(wRng, docEnds.Length, docEnds[0].Length);
        wTable.set_Style("Table Grid");

        for (int i = 0; i < docEnds.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < docEnds[0].Length; j++)
            {
                wTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text = docEnds[i][j];
                wTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
                wTable.Cell(1, 1).VerticalAlignment = WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
            }
        }
        Borders wb = wTable.Borders;
        wb[WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal].LineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
        wb[WdBorderType.wdBorderVertical].LineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;

        wTable.Borders = wb;
    }
```

Where WordDoc is of type Document from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace;

Comment: Can't i do it via token?
Actually i have different tokens on the tempalte where some are simple string which i think can be easily replaced while others are token which have to be replaced by the genreated Table

Comment: You can do it using string but it involves a little more you have to use something like this `object start = 0;
object end = 0;
Word.Range tableLocation = this.Range(ref start, ref end);` where you replace start and end with the index of you're string, I really don't recommend it but it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can search document content using [Find Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and its [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method. First argument is text to search in range (in your case i would recommend Word.Document.Content property) from which find object was created.

Code:

```
Word.Document doc = Application.ActiveDocument;
Word.Range wholeDoc = doc.Content;                

Word.Find find = wholeDoc.Find;

object token = "[MyTableToken]";                
object missing = Type.Missing;

bool result = find.Execute(ref token, true, true, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

while (result)
{
    // wholeDoc object is replaced with executed search/find result
    CreateTable(wholeDoc.Duplicate);

    result = find.Execute(ref token, true, true, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

sample create table method:

```
private void CreateTable(Word.Range range)
{
    Word.Tables tables = null;
    try
    {
        int sampleRowNumber = 3, sampleColumnNumber = 3;

        range.Text = "";
        tables = range.Tables;

        tables.Add(range, sampleRowNumber, sampleColumnNumber);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tables);
    }
}
```